# What is the level cap with the Season Pass?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, the default level cap is Level 50. If you own either Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 1 or Pack 2, the level cap becomes Level 61, and if you own both, it becomes Level 72.

What is the level cap with the Season Pass?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Season Pass includes only the Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 1. It does not include Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2: Digistruct Peak Challenge.

Therefore, the level cap with the Season Pass is Level 61.

Answer (score 0):

The newest level cap is 72, like with the new DLC package. http://www.gamesradar.com/borderlands-2-dlc-raises-games-level-cap-today/